# "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" not working - UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Using Jupyter notebook via Anaconda2 on a Windows7 OS 64-bit launching it with GraphLabCreate.  Getting the following error when executing the command "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt".

Is it anything to do with the environmental variables as I'm using GraphLabCreate?  They have the following from a tool bar command selection:

```
set "PATH=C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2;C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2\Scripts;%PATH%"
```

I've gone ahead and checked the environmental variables and they are listed as above (except for the %PATH% part).  Here are the PATH variables on my computer:

```
C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2;C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2\Scripts;C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2\Library\bin;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\x64
```

Here is the entire error output:

```
    UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-6f467123fe04> in <module>()
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot

C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in <module>()
     27 from cycler import cycler
     28 import matplotlib
---> 29 import matplotlib.colorbar
     30 from matplotlib import style
     31 from matplotlib import _pylab_helpers, interactive

C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py in <module>()
     32 import matplotlib.artist as martist
     33 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
---> 34 import matplotlib.collections as collections
     35 import matplotlib.colors as colors
     36 import matplotlib.contour as contour

C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py in <module>()
     25 import matplotlib.artist as artist
     26 from matplotlib.artist import allow_rasterization
---> 27 import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
     28 import matplotlib.path as mpath
     29 from matplotlib import _path

C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py in <module>()
     60 
     61 import matplotlib.tight_bbox as tight_bbox
---> 62 import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
     63 from matplotlib.path import Path
     64 from matplotlib.cbook import mplDeprecation, warn_deprecated

C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\textpath.py in <module>()
     13 from matplotlib.path import Path
     14 from matplotlib import rcParams
---> 15 import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
     16 from matplotlib.ft2font import FT2Font, KERNING_DEFAULT, LOAD_NO_HINTING
     17 from matplotlib.ft2font import LOAD_TARGET_LIGHT

C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py in <module>()
   1419                 verbose.report("Using fontManager instance from %s" % _fmcache)
   1420         except:
-> 1421             _rebuild()
   1422     else:
   1423         _rebuild()

C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py in _rebuild()
   1404     def _rebuild():
   1405         global fontManager
-> 1406         fontManager = FontManager()
   1407         if _fmcache:
   1408             pickle_dump(fontManager, _fmcache)

C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py in __init__(self, size, weight)
   1042         #  Load TrueType fonts and create font dictionary.
   1043 
-> 1044         self.ttffiles = findSystemFonts(paths) + findSystemFonts()
   1045         self.defaultFamily = {
   1046             'ttf': 'Bitstream Vera Sans',

C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py in findSystemFonts(fontpaths, fontext)
    311             fontpaths = [fontdir]
    312             # now get all installed fonts directly...
--> 313             for f in win32InstalledFonts(fontdir):
    314                 base, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    315                 if len(ext)>1 and ext[1:].lower() in fontexts:

C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py in win32InstalledFonts(directory, fontext)
    228                         continue
    229                     if not os.path.dirname(direc):
--> 230                         direc = os.path.join(directory, direc)
    231                     direc = os.path.abspath(direc).lower()
    232                     if os.path.splitext(direc)[1][1:] in fontext:

C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\ntpath.pyc in join(path, *paths)
     83         if result_path and result_path[-1] not in '\\/':
     84             result_path = result_path + '\\'
---> 85         result_path = result_path + p_path
     86     ## add separator between UNC and non-absolute path
     87     if (result_path and result_path[0] not in '\\/' and

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: For error messages, it's perhaps helpful to post the entire output

Comment: which python version are you using ?

Comment: do you have any fancy (accented) characters in your current working directory?

Comment: I've edited my original question with the entire error output. I'm using Python 2.7.13 | Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit). The python.exe. file is located here C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda2.  No accented characters in the current working directory as far as I can tell.

Comment: If I execute "import matplotlib" I don't get any error. If I execute "import matplotlib.pyplot" I get the error above.